# SQLite: Tags and Products intersection

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I'm new to SQLite and searching for a way to create a query to do the following:

I have 3 tables:

```
goods: List of goods
tags: list of tags
tag_goods: table used to associate a tag to a product
```

This is the structure for each table:

Goods:

```
id (INTEGER, autoincrement)
name (TEXT, name of the product)
```

Tags:

```
id (INTEGER, autoincrement)
name (TEXT, name of the tag)
```

Tag_goods:

```
tag_id (INTEGER)
goods_id (INTEGER)
UNIQUE (tag_id, goods_id)
```

What I want:

Obtain ONLY ids and names of the products that are tagged with ALL of the possible tags (NB: I need to reference all the tags in the query, not one by one).

(Meaning, for example I only have four tags: "yellow", "round", "eatable", "organic" and only goods "Cheese" and "Melon" match all of them)

With my very limited experience I understand, that I can try something like intersect, but it is impractical when there are too many tags.

Answer (score 2):

This query:

```
select goods_id
from tag_goods
group by goods_id
having count(*) = (select count(*) from tags)
```

returns all the `id`s of goods that have all the tags from `tags`.
You can use it to return the rows from the table `goods` with the operator `IN`:

```
select * from goods
where id in (
  select goods_id
  from tag_goods
  group by goods_id
  having count(*) = (select count(*) from tags)
)
```